# In Linux, how to unlink a softlink from the actual file if both have same names

Tags: linux, unix, symlink

I have a softlink mistakenly created as this:

```
/backup_rmbeir1 -> /backup_rmbeir1
```

I want to delete the soft link now. If I do :

```
rm /backup_rmbeir1
```

will this delete the link, or the actual file ? If not what will be the best way to achieve this ? I tried the `unlink` command but didn't help.

Comment: That's a link pointing to itself. I don't think you can even create such a link

Comment: How can you create two files with identical name in one directory ? Are there any trailing blank spaces?

Comment: @knittl it is possible, I've done it by mistake..

Comment: [root@labeir1 /]# ls -lrth /backup
total 4.0K
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Nov  7 17:41 backup_labeir1 -> /backup_labeir1

Comment: @Siddharth when I did it by mistake last time, the symbol link was created and overwrote the original file, the original file was gone, unfortunately.

Comment: @Siddharth: that's one link `/backup/backup_labeir1` pointing to `/backup_labeir1`.

Comment: Remove the link file: `/backup/backup_labeir1`

Comment: @HowardGuo Ohh, god...anyway to come out of this ? Actually i have some automated scripts to be run after this step, and this will confuse the scripts.

Comment: @Siddharth I was trying to fix a software package in OpenSUSE (it was Java probably), then in a confusion, I created a symbol link using `ln -sf` which overwrote the original file.

Comment: Please elaborate why can't you remove the link `/backup/backup_labeir1`

Comment: @knittl any insights how you arrived at this `that's one link /backup/backup_labeir1 pointing to /backup_labeir1`

Comment: @Siddarth: Your `ls /backup` shows this.

Comment: The output you have shown shows that the file `/backup/backup_labeir1` is a link file. Because `ls` was executed in the directory `/backup` and it has got `l` in the first charecter in the permissions and modes string of `ls`. Also you will see the link destination file in the `ls` output. `rm` will not follow the link and remove the file.

Comment: @knittl thanks again, worked

Answer (score 3):

The soft link is `/backup/backup_rmbeir1`, so delete that by `rm /backup/backup_rmbeir1`.